# How to know the date when an image has been capturing on Google Hybrid QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

How can I know precisly the date of different Google Hybrid pictures used in my project in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot know the exact date because Google only publishes the year when the data was collected (as displayed in the lower right corner of the image).

Comment: ... but only in low zoomlevels on the website. I don't see that in the openlayers plugin.

Comment: Google Earth will go down to month/year but not actual date.